# PHP-ERROR: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

I am inserting values in mysql database but i am receiving same error again and again. I also looked over stackoverflow but none of those questions solved my query. I also re-checked my query values with database column. All values are mapping to their corresponding columns in database:

Here is the PHP code for insert:

> "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$title', '$category', '$tags' '$details', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 'no', 0)"

Database fields are as follow:

> id, title, category, tags, details, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes

I have tried finding solution over internet and stackoverflow but every solution referred that columns count is mismatched in either database or insert query. But i didn't find this error in my code.

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$title', '$category', '$tags' '$details', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 'no', 0)");
```

I expect values to enter in database but they are not entering and i am facing error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** For instance, multiple single quotes in any of your text fields will break your query.

Comment: have tried passing column name too ?

Comment: @aynber i don't think that the question

Comment: @aynber is 100% correct. However your issue is that you are not specifying the columns to enter data into. The problem is your id column is not being used. So there are 11 columns and only 10 values.

Comment: need use column name insert structure.

Comment: Without the full error message, which often has the full query in it, it's hard to say exactly where the issue might lie. But using prepared statements will most likely take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this structure on insert:

```
$strQuery = "INSERT INTO posts (id, title, category, tags, details, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes) VALUES('','$title', '$category', '$tags' '$details', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 'no', 0)";

$query = mysqli_query($this->con, $strQuery);
```

if ID is Auto-incrment key you can make the insert without it... like this (10 Column and Values):

```
$strQuery = "INSERT INTO posts (title, category, tags, details, added_by, user_to, date_added, user_closed, deleted, likes) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$tags' '$details', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 'no', 0)";

$query = mysqli_query($this->con, $strQuery);
```